# Checking multiple conditions in a switch statement

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I've got a Swift function that uses a switch statement to act on various enum cases but I also need to check for another condition at the same time. The best solution I can come up with is to use a nested switch (which works) but I was wondering if there was a more elegant (Swifty?) way?

The code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
func transitionTo(scene: Scene, transition: SceneTransitionType) -> Observable<Void> {

let subject = PublishSubject<Void>()
let viewController = scene.viewController()

switch viewController {
case is UISplitViewController:
    switch transition {
    case .root:
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        subject.onCompleted()
    default:
        fatalError("UISplitViewController can only be exist at the root of the view hierachy")
    }
default:
    switch transition {
    case .root:
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        subject.onCompleted()
    case .push(let animated):
        guard let nc = currentViewController as? UINavigationController else {
            fatalError("Unab;e to push a view controlled without an existing navigation controller")
        }
        _ = nc.rx.delegate // one-off sub to be notified when push complete
            .sentMessage(#selector(UINavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)))
            .map { _ in }
            .bind(to: subject)
        nc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        currentViewController = SceneCoordinator.topViewControllerInStackWith(root: viewController).first!
    case .modal(let animated):
        currentViewController.present(viewController, animated: animated) {
            subject.onCompleted()
        }
        currentViewController = SceneCoordinator.topViewControllerInStackWith(root: viewController).first!
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use only one switch block, and in each case you should check for condition i.e UISplitViewController or not in case of .root

Comment: Your current state is encoded in viewController and your new state in transition. You could make enum out of the former  and then a switch on (currentState, transition) and in the default you handle transitions you do not allow.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best possible way as per my knowledge with single switch statement.

```
func transitionTo(scene: Scene, transition: SceneTransitionType) -> Observable<Void> {

    let subject = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let viewController = scene.viewController()

    switch transition {
    case .root:
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        subject.onCompleted()
    case .push(let animated):
        if viewController is UISplitViewController {
            fatalError("UISplitViewController can only be exist at the root of the view hierachy")
            return
        }
        guard let nc = currentViewController as? UINavigationController else {
            fatalError("Unab;e to push a view controlled without an existing navigation controller")
        }
        _ = nc.rx.delegate // one-off sub to be notified when push complete
            .sentMessage(#selector(UINavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)))
            .map { _ in }
            .bind(to: subject)
        nc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        currentViewController = SceneCoordinator.topViewControllerInStackWith(root: viewController).first!
    case .modal(let animated):
        if viewController is UISplitViewController {
            fatalError("UISplitViewController can only be exist at the root of the view hierachy")
            return
        }
        currentViewController.present(viewController, animated: animated) {
            subject.onCompleted()
        }
        currentViewController = SceneCoordinator.topViewControllerInStackWith(root: viewController).first!
    }
}
```